# fprintf en documentos con estructuras en C

Tags: c, archivo, estructuras

Tengo un problema con un código que requiere que almacene el nombre de una asignatura junto a su nota en un fichero y después lo guarde en un fichero, siguiente el formato `"[nombre]\t[nota]"`.

He comprobado que se guarden bien las variables en el array de tipo nota, pero a la hora de guardarlo en el fichero da un segmentation fault y no consigo encontrar la manera de hacerlo funcionar correctamente.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar y explicarme que es lo que ocurre lo agradecería. Muchas gracias por leer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NFIL 50
#define NCOL 50
    
typedef struct
{
    char v[NFIL];
    float nota;
} notas;
    
int funcion (int *tlogico,notas p[NFIL]);
    
int main()
{
    int f,i;
    notas p[NFIL];
    funcion(&f,p);
    for (i=0;i<f;i++){
         printf("%s   %f",p[i].v,p[i].nota);
    }
}
int funcion (int *tlogico,notas p[NFIL])
{
    int i,d;
    FILE*f;
    fopen("notas.txt","w");
    if (f==NULL)
        printf("El fichero no se ha podido abrir correctamente\n");
    else
    {
        printf("¿Cuantas asignaturas tienes?\n");
        scanf("%d",&d);
        *tlogico=d;
        for(i=0;i<d;i++)
        {
            printf("Introduzca la asignatura y, a continuacion, introduzca la nota sacada en esa asignatura\n");
            scanf("%s",p[i].v);
            scanf("%f",&p[i].nota);
            fprintf(f, "%s\t%f",p[i].v,p[i].nota); //Aqui CREO que es donde esta el error
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se te ha olvidado guardar el retorno de `fopen`:

```
FILE*f;                 // Puntero a 'FILE', no se le asigna valor.
fopen("notas.txt","w"); // 'fopen' devuelve el puntero a 'FILE', se pierde porque no lo guardas.
```

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) (y algún otro lenguaje), si no inicializas una variable ésta obtiene un valor indeterminado, este valor muy probablemente no sea `NULL` y por eso superas la condición:

```
if (f==NULL) // no se sabe lo que es 'f', probablemente no sea 'NULL'.
    printf("El fichero no se ha podido abrir correctamente\n");
else
{
    ...

    fprintf(f, "%s\t%f",p[i].v,p[i].nota); // Usas 'f' que no esta inicializado, esto provoca el error.

    ...
}
```

Lo que pretendías hacer es esto:

```
FILE *f = fopen("notas.txt","w");
```